# Use Model::create() to fill specific columns

Tags: laravel-5.7, laravel-5.8

I just found out that input data to db on laravel could use `Model::create()` but my question is what if i want to submit specific column? How do i do it? For example table user with name, email, address, and phone. Bug only input the name only without email, address, and phone.

Comment: You question is not clear if you can explain in little more detail or example it would easy to answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this

```
 Model::create(['name' => $name]);
```

But make sure to make other columns email, address, and phone nullable or keep the default value for them, else it will throw any error.

**Note:**
*If you are using MySQL database, then you have to set the default to nullable from MySQL database data structure.*

> But if you are using MongoDB with Laravel then you don't need to set other fields as nullable Because MongoDB is an unstructured (NoSql) database.